# How could I use these local variables for object position in my main function?

Tags: c++, vector, global-variables, computer-vision, local-variables

I'm using some computer vision code in c++ that tracks an object after you draw a bounding box around it, and it can track multiple objects with multiple bounding boxes. In one of the header files there is a function that processes the frame and defines the objects center pixel coordinates as variables `centerx` and `centery`, but I need to be able to use these variable in the main cpp file.

In this part of the function `oldcenterx` and `oldcentery` are defined:

EDIT: Added `bool LKTracker::processFrame(const Matrix& curImage, ObjectBox& bbox, bool dotracking)`

```
bool LKTracker::processFrame(const Matrix& curImage, ObjectBox& bbox, bool dotracking)
{
  std::vector<ObjectBox> boxes;
  std::vector<bool> isDefined;
  boxes.push_back(bbox);
  isDefined.push_back(dotracking);
  processFrame(curImage, boxes, isDefined);
  bbox = boxes[0];
  return isDefined[0];
}

void LKTracker::processFrame(const Matrix& curImage, std::vector<ObjectBox>& bbox, std::vector<bool>& isDefined)
{
  int nobs = bbox.size();
  if (nobs > 0 && !ivPrevPyramid)
    initFirstFrame(curImage);
  #if DEBUG
  std::cout << "#" << (ivIndex+1) << " LKTracker: ";
  #endif
  ivDebugPoints.clear();
  LKPyramid* curPyramid = new LKPyramid(MAX_PYRAMID_LEVEL+1);
  curPyramid->I[0] = curImage;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PYRAMID_LEVEL; ++i)
  {
    curPyramid->I[i].halfSizeImage(curPyramid->I[i+1]);
    #if DEBUG > 1
    char filename[255];
    sprintf(filename, "output/img%05d-%d.ppm", ivIndex, i);
    curPyramid->I[i].writeToPGM(filename);
    #endif  
  }

  #pragma omp parallel sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
      //#pragma omp parallel for
      for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PYRAMID_LEVEL; ++i)
        curPyramid->I[i].scharrDerivativeX(curPyramid->Ix[i]);
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      //#pragma omp parallel for
      for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PYRAMID_LEVEL; ++i)
        curPyramid->I[i].scharrDerivativeY(curPyramid->Iy[i]);
    }
  }

  #if DEBUG > 1
  Matrix debugFlow(ivWidth, ivHeight, 0);
  #endif

  // loop over all object boxes
  for (int obj = 0; obj < nobs; obj++)
  {
    #if DEBUG
    std::cout << "\tObj" << obj << ": ";
    #endif
    if (isDefined[obj])
    {
      float oldwidth = bbox[obj].width, 
            oldheight = bbox[obj].height,
            oldcenterx = bbox[obj].x + oldwidth*0.5, 
            oldcentery = bbox[obj].y + oldheight*0.5;
```

And then `centerx` and `centery` are defined later in this section:

```
// Compute median flow
  std::vector<float> deltax;
  std::vector<float> deltay;
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    if (status[i] > 0)
    {
      deltax.push_back(points1[i].x - points0[i].x);
      deltay.push_back(points1[i].y - points0[i].y);
      ++num;
      #if DEBUG > 1
      debugFlow.drawLine(points0[i].x, points0[i].y, points1[i].x, points1[i].y, 255);
      debugFlow.drawCross(points1[i].x, points1[i].y, 255);
      #endif
    }
  }
  if (num < 4)
  {
    #if DEBUG
    std::cout << "n=" << num << " => FAILURE: lost object" << std::endl;
    #endif
    isDefined[obj] = false;
    continue;
  }
  //else

  float dx = median(&deltax),
        dy = median(&deltay);  

  // Remove outliers
  /*
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    if (status[i] > 0)
      if ((points1[i].x - points0[i].x - dx) * (points1[i].x - points0[i].x - dx)
          + (points1[i].y - points0[i].y - dy) * (points1[i].y - points0[i].y - dy) > 5*5)
      {
        status[i] = 0;
        num--;
      }
  */

  // Resize bounding box (compute median elongation factor)
  float s = 1;
  if (num >= 16){
    std::vector<float> d2;
    float dpx,dpy,ddx,ddy;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      if (status[i] > 0)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; ++j)
          if (status[j] > 0)
          {
            ddx = points0[i].x - points0[j].x;
            ddy = points0[i].y - points0[j].y;
            dpx = points1[i].x - points1[j].x;
            dpy = points1[i].y - points1[j].y;
            d2.push_back((dpx*dpx + dpy*dpy) / (ddx*ddx + ddy*ddy));
          }

    if (!d2.empty())
    {
      s = median(&d2, true);
      //upper bound for enlargement
      //s = std::min(1.1, s);
    }
  }
  //delete[] points0; delete[] points1; delete[] points2;
  //delete[] status; delete[] fb; delete[] ncc;

  float  centerx = oldcenterx + dx, 
         centery = oldcentery + dy;

  bbox[obj].x = (centerx - s * oldwidth * 0.5);
  bbox[obj].y = (centery - s * oldheight * 0.5);
  bbox[obj].width  = s * oldwidth;
  bbox[obj].height = s * oldheight;
```

One thing I have done so far is defined `centerx` and `centery` globally at the top of the header file. This works great for the time being and I can use the data I need, but this only gives position data for the object in the most recently drawn bounding box so I can only get the pixel coordinates of one object.

I also tried defining a global vector like this:

```
std::vector<ObjectCenter> objcenter;
```

so then

```
objcenter[obj].objcenterx = centerx;
```

But I would keep getting errors that the vector is not initialized, or the code would unexpectedly quit running with no errors.

EDIT: Here is the `ObjectBox` struct:

```
/// datastructure linking objects to their (possible) location
struct ObjectBox
{
  /// x-component of top left coordinate
  float x;
  /// y-component of top left coordinate
  float y;
  /// width of the image section
  float width;
  /// height of the image section
  float height;
  /// identifies object, which is represented by ObjectBox
  int objectId;
};
```

PS: Thank you for the help. I'm a n00b.
-Tyler

Comment: You have a class, `LKTracker`. Can't you store them in the class and provide read accessors?

Comment: I can try it out I'm just not too familiar with how to do that but I'll look around the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have access to the parameters being passed to this function `void LKTracker::processFrame(const Matrix& curImage, std::vector<ObjectBox>& bbox, std::vector<bool>& isDefined)`

I think your two best options are:

1. Calculate the center from the bbox (ObjectBox) x, width and y, height values. You can create functions to make it cleaner:

   ```
   // add these functions to your code
   float getCenterX(ObjectBox bbox)
   {
       float centerx = bbox.x + bbox.width * 0.5;
       return centerx;
   }
   float getCenterY(ObjectBox bbox)
   {
       float centery = bbox.y + bbox.height * 0.5;
       return centery;
   }
   ```

   Using it from main, if the variable is similarly named bbox in main

   ```
     int index = 0;
     float centerX = getCenterX(bbox[index]);
     float centerY = getCenterY(bbox[index]);
   ```
2. Add new xcenter and ycenter members to the ObjectBox struct and store the center values during the calculations in the processFrame method. For this to work you need access to the ObjectBox source code and need to recompile it. Just add to the ObjectBox class (or struct) definition in the header file

   ```
   float centerx; 
   float centery;
   ```

then you can change the code in the processFrame method from:

```
  //delete[] points0; delete[] points1; delete[] points2;
  //delete[] status; delete[] fb; delete[] ncc;

  float  centerx = oldcenterx + dx, 
         centery = oldcentery + dy;

  bbox[obj].x = (centerx - s * oldwidth * 0.5);
  bbox[obj].y = (centery - s * oldheight * 0.5);
  bbox[obj].width  = s * oldwidth;
  bbox[obj].height = s * oldheight;
```

to:

```
  //delete[] points0; delete[] points1; delete[] points2;
  //delete[] status; delete[] fb; delete[] ncc;

  bbox[obj].centerx = oldcenterx + dx, 
  bbox[obj].centery = oldcentery + dy;

  bbox[obj].x = (bbox[obj].centerx - s * oldwidth * 0.5);
  bbox[obj].y = (bbox[obj].centery - s * oldheight * 0.5);
  bbox[obj].width  = s * oldwidth;
  bbox[obj].height = s * oldheight;
```

you could also then improve the oldcenterx code from:

```
        oldcenterx = bbox[obj].x + oldwidth*0.5, 
        oldcentery = bbox[obj].y + oldheight*0.5;
```

to:

```
        oldcenterx = bbox[obj].centerx, 
        oldcentery = bbox[obj].centery;
```

Hope this helps! There might be syntax errors...

EDIT: From the code provided for the BoundingBox struct, implementing Option 2. above you should edit it from:

```
/// datastructure linking objects to their (possible) location
struct ObjectBox
{
  /// x-component of top left coordinate
  float x;
  /// y-component of top left coordinate
  float y;
  /// width of the image section
  float width;
  /// height of the image section
  float height;
  /// identifies object, which is represented by ObjectBox
  int objectId;
};
```

to

```
/// datastructure linking objects to their (possible) location
struct ObjectBox
{
  /// x-component of top left coordinate
  float x;
  /// y-component of top left coordinate
  float y;
  /// width of the image section
  float width;
  /// height of the image section
  float height;
  /// identifies object, which is represented by ObjectBox
  int objectId;
  /// x-component of center coordinate
  float centerx;
  /// y-component of center coordinate
  float centery;
};
```

If you then make the change already provided in the processFrame code you should be able to get the centerx and centery coordenates from any bounding box.

It seems the problem you are having is how to access the actual boundingbox. I suggest you search the code for all calls to the processFrame function and see where the ObjectBox object is created and stored before it is passed to the processFrame function to see how you can reach it.

Perhaps you could add some more code to explain better exactly where the problem is coming in.

Comment: This looks like the best option but it doesn't look like I have access to `bbox` possibly because another function `bool LKTracker::processFrame` (see edit to first part of code). Thank you!

Comment: If I try use `bbox` anywhere else it says it is not defined in this scope. I also added the `ObjectBox` struct.

Comment: I think you need to do some general C++ tutorials (CodeProject has a lot of good ones) and work on some small projects before taking on something complicated like bounding box tracking etc. But let's see if we can get this working for you. I will edit my answer with more details.

Comment: Yes, I do need/want to properly learn C++ but this is part of a mechanical engineering project (I'm not sure why, it's all programming which we aren't really taught. Thanks for the good resource.) and it's getting to be crunch time. Anyway, I finally figured it out. The problem I was having was accessing `bbox` outside of anything other than the `processFrame` function, but I used some of what you gave me and created a new struct `getCenter` to work around it. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter objcenter in the function processFrame() so that main function can get the data.
void LKTracker::processFrame(const Matrix& curImage, std::vector& bbox, std::vector& isDefined, **vector & objcenter**)

Comment: I'll have to try it later and do more work with it but it caused a whole mess of errors.